# .Net Core 3 HtmlGrid WithFooter not an option

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, .net-core

I am a noob when it comes to .Net Core and I was asked to upgrade an existing project from Core 2.2 to 3.1.  I have been slowly working though the issues but this one I can not find any help on.

I am getting an error:

> CS1061    'IHtmlGrid' does not contain a definition for
>   'WithFooter' and no accessible extension method 'WithFooter' accepting
>   a first argument of type 'IHtmlGrid' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is the full page code from my FollowupOnTimeGrid.cshtml:

```
@(Html.Grid(Model)
    .Build(c =>
    {
        c.Add(m => m.SurveyDateRange).Titled("Survey Period").InitialSort(GridSortOrder.Asc);
        c.Add(m => m.Due);
        c.Add(m => String.Format("{0} ({1:f2}%)", m.OnTime, m.Due == 0 ? 0 
           : Math.Round((((double)m.OnTime) / m.Due) * 100.0, 2)))
                 .Titled("Surveys Taken on Time (N (%))");
    })
    .Css("table-striped table-bordered table-hover")
    .Named("FollowupOnTimeGrid")
    .Empty("No Records Found!")
    .WithFooter("_FollowupOnTimeGridFooter")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution.  NonFactor changed the .WithFooter to .UsingFooter in release 7.

Comment: The notes can be found here: https://github.com/NonFactors/MVC5.Grid/issues/80